# Best Practice : Print an array in a bash script

Tags: arrays, bash, unix, scripting, shellcheck

I ran `shellcheck` on my script and ran into an error on a very simple aspect -

> echo "List of fields deleted: ${deleted[@]}"
>                                  ^-----------^ SC2145: Argument mixes string and array. Use * or separate argument.

I am trying to do similar behavior as below-

```
declare -a  deleted
deleted = ("some.id.1" "some.id.22" "some.id.333")
echo "List of fields deleted: ${deleted[@]}"
```

Which is a better practice to print the elements in the array?

```
echo "List of fields deleted: ${deleted[@]}"
```

OR

```
echo "List of fields deleted: "
 for deletedField in "${deleted[@]}"; do echo "${deletedField}"; done
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Including a `@`-indexed array inside a longer string can make for some weird results:

```
$ arr=(a b c)
$ printf '%s\n' "Hi there ${arr[@]}"
Hi there a
b
c
```

This happens because the quoted expansion of `${arr[@]}` is a series of *separate* words, which `printf` will use one at a time. The first word `a` ends up with `Hi there` prepended to it (just as anything following the array would be appended to `c`).

When the array expansion is part of a larger string, you almost certainly want the expansion to be a single word instead.

```
$ printf '%s\n' "Hi there ${arr[*]}"
Hi there a b c
```

With `echo`, it barely matters, as you probably don't care whether `echo` is receiving one or multiple arguments.

Comment: Thanks! That clarifies my doubt.