# Append elements to an array in bash

Tags: arrays, bash

I tried the `+=` operator to append an array in bash but do not know why it did not work

```
#!/bin/bash

i=0
args=()
while [ $i -lt 5 ]; do
    args+=("${i}")
    echo "${args}"
    let i=i+1
done
```

expected results

```
0
0 1
0 1 2
0 1 2 3
0 1 2 3 4
```

actual results

```
0
0
0
0
0
```

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: It does work. However, `echo "${args}"` only shows the first element. You need to change it to `echo "${args[@]}"` to output all elements

Comment: Slightly OT, but `i=0 ... while [ $i -lt 5 ]; do ... let i=i+1 ... done` can be replaced with `for ((i=0; i<5; ++i)); do ... done`

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Expanding a bash array only gives the first element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47367985/expanding-a-bash-array-only-gives-the-first-element)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

It did work, but you're only echoing the first element of the array. Use this instead:

```
echo "${args[@]}"
```

Bash's syntax for arrays is confusing. Use `${args[@]}` to get all the elements of the array. Using `${args}` is equivalent to `${args[0]}`, which gets the first element (at index 0).

See [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/): [Expanding an array without an index only gives the first element.](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2128)

Also btw you can simplify `let i=i+1` to `((i++))`, but it's even simpler to use a C-style `for` loop. And also you don't need to define `args` before adding to it.

So:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
for ((i=0; i<5; ++i)); do
    args+=($i)
    echo "${args[@]}"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
for ((i=0; i<5; ++i)); do
  args+=($i)
  echo "${args[@]}"
done
```

```
$ ./run.sh "1 2 3" "4 5 6"
0
0 1
0 1 2
0 1 2 3
0 1 2 3 4
```

I think this is more what you're looking for ...

```
#! /bin/bash

for (( i = 1; i <= ${#@}; i++ ))
do
  args[${i}]="${!i}"
done

for (( i = 1; i <= ${#args[@]}; i++ ))
do
  echo "${args[${i}]}"
done
```

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).