# how to append one element to a GNU bash array variable and use that array variable as arguments to an ELF executable

Tags: linux, bash

In the [Bismon](https://github.com/bstarynk/bismon/) static source code analyzer (GPLv3+ licensed, [git commit `49dd1bd232854a`](https://github.com/bstarynk/bismon/commit/49dd1bd232854acd3337e98974e35d229f0d82d2)) for embedded C and C++ code (using a plugin for [GCC 10](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-10/) straight compiler on [Debian](https://debian.org/) bookworm for x86-64) I have a test [Bash script `Hello-World-Analyze`](https://github.com/bstarynk/bismon/blob/master/Hello-World-Analyze) which uses a GNU array variable `bismon_hello_args`.

That variable is declared (at line 56) using:

```
declare -a bismon_hello_args
```

and I would like to fill that `bismon_hello_args` *array* variable from script arguments starting with `--bismon`, and later invoke the `bismon` executable (compiled from C source files) with several arguments to its `main` being the elements of that `bismon_hello_args` *array* variable.

So if my `Hello-World-Analyze` script is invoked as `Hello-World-Analyze --bismon-debug-after-load --bismon-anon-web-cookie=/tmp/bismoncookie --gcc=/usr/local/bin/gcc-11` I want the `bismon` ELF executable to be started with two arguments (so argc=3, in C parlance) : `--bismon-debug-after-load` followed by `--bismon-anon-web-cookie=/tmp/bismoncookie`

For some reason, the following code (lines 58 to 64) in that `Hello-World-Analyze` script:

```
for f in "$@"; do
    case "$f" in
    --bismon*) bismon_hello_args+=$f;;
    --asm) export BISMON_PLUGIN_ASMOUT=/tmp/gcc10_metaplugin_BMGCC.s;;
    --gcc=*) export BISMON_GCC=$(echo $f | /bin/sed -e s/--gcc=//);;
    esac
done
```

does not work as expected. It should be (and was in a previous [git commit `e8c3d795bc9dc8`](https://github.com/bstarynk/bismon/commit/e8c3d795bc9dc8949f)) later followed with

```
./bismon $bismon_hello_args &
```

But debugging prints show that `bismon` is invoked with `argc=2` so one long `argv[1]` program argument...

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Merely `+=` adds a string to an existing string. You probably want `bismon_hello_args+=("$f");;` (notice also the quotes). To call the program, use `./bismon "${bismon_hello_args[@]}" &` (notice the quotes, again).

Comment: Thanks. Why was my question closed? If your comment was an answer, I would accept it!

Comment: This does not seem to be closed yet, but basic syntax questions usually get closed as "typo / unreproducible" or as duplicates of previous similar questions. I could not find a suitable duplicate so I voted to close as typo.

Comment: It is not a syntax question, but a semantics one....

Comment: The syntax for getting array semantics is different. It's clumsy (mostly for reasons of backwards compatibility with the original Bourne shell) but well documented.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch : Since `bismon_hello_args`  is an array, you should pass its element to another script by `./bismon "${bismon_hello_args[@]}" &`.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch : `bismon_hello_args+=$f` catenates to the first element of the array (i.e. to index postition 0).  See [here](https://linuxhandbook.com/bash-arrays/) for how to properly handle arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Merely `+=` adds a string to an existing string. You probably want `bismon_hello_args+=("$f");;` (notice also the quotes). To call the program, use `./bismon "${bismon_hello_args[@]}" &` (notice the quotes, again).

The syntax to use an array variable is different than the syntax for simple scalars. This syntax was inherited from `ksh`, which in turn needed to find a way to introduce new behavior without sacrificing compatibility with existing Bourne shell scripts.

Without the array modifiers, Bash simply [accesses the first element of the array.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47367985/expanding-a-bash-array-only-gives-the-first-element) (This confuses beginners and experienced practitioners alike.)