# How to write a bash script to find files with complex conditions

Tags: linux, bash, shell, find

> **Expected Function**: write a bash script showing all the regular files
> with filename ended with ".xml" or ".yml" and with path not begined
> with "./target/", i.e., exclude the "target" subdirectory.

> **Example File List**:  ./a/a1.xml; ./a/a2.txt; ./b/b1.yml; ./target/t.xml;
> **Example Outout**: ./a/a1.xml; ./b/b1.yml

I construct `find` options in a bash shell script like

```
#!/bin/bash
find_opts=( -type f -a ( -not -path "./target/*" ) -a ( -false -o -name "*.xml" -o -name "*.yml" ) )
find . $find_opts
```

But it does not output the expected result. Howver, when I tpye the full command string in bash terminal as follows:

```
[root@localhost]#find . \( -type f -a \( -not -path "./target/*" \) -a \( -false -o -name "*.xml" -o -name "*.yml" \) \)
```

it works. What is the problem about the above bash script ?

==============================================================

Someone gives this reference link : [Expanding a bash array only gives the first element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47367985/expanding-a-bash-array-only-gives-the-first-element)

It is about "bash array". But it seems that my problem is not about "bash array". Would anyone give any reasons?

Please see [How to exclude a directory in find . command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4210042/how-to-exclude-a-directory-in-find-command) to known why I use parentheses whiches look like an array. Anyway, I try two others attempts:

```
#the first one
find_opts=( -type f -a ( -not -path "./target/*" ) -a ( -false -o -name "*.xml" -o -name "*.yml" ) )
#the second one
find_opts=\\( -type f -a \\( -not -path "./target/*" \\) -a \\( -false -o -name "*.xml" -o -name "*.yml" \\) \\)
#the third one
find_opts=\( -type f -a \( -not -path "./target/*" \) -a \( -false -o -name "*.xml" -o -name "*.yml" \) \)
```

The first one and the third one give the same output which is unexpeced result. The second one occures an error.

> syntax error near unexpected token `('

The problem is still here.

==============================================================

Someone give one more reference:[Why does shell ignore quoting characters in arguments passed to it through variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12136948/why-does-shell-ignore-quoting-characters-in-arguments-passed-to-it-through-varia)
It is about how to use bash array to pass arguments and the problem is solved by the following code:

```
#!/bin/bash
find_opts=(\( -type f -a \( -not -path './target/*' \) -a \( -false -o -name '*.xml' -o -name '*.yml' \) \))
find . "${find_opts[@]}"
```

Comment: The immediate problem is that you are using the wrong syntax to refer to the array; see the duplicate. But furthermore, your conditions are artificially complex. They can be reduced to `find . -type f \( -not -path "./target/*" \) -name "*.[xy]ml"`

Comment: @tripleee I think there is no array in my case.Can you point out which variable shoule be array ?

Comment: It's not a matter of belief. `find_opts=( ... )` creates an array with the values in `...`. Not using an array is broken for other reasons; I'm adding a separate duplicate about that.

Comment: @tripleee It (`find_opts`) is not intended to be an array if you use `find` to do the same task. So I change my code. But the problem is still. Please see the edited OP.

Comment: `find_opts=\( -type ...` assigns the opening parenthesis to the string variable `find_opts`  for the duration of the attempt to run `-type ...` as a command. Probably review [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable); but again, as the second duplicate points out, basically never attempt to use a string variable to store nontrivial command options.

Comment: Tangentially, questions should remain strictly questions, but it doesn't matter much here, as [low-traffic duplicates typically get deleted after a while.](/help/roomba)

Comment: There appears to be no compelling reason to use a variable for part of your command here anyway; probably the basic lesson here really is just "don't do that."