# Working around "expanding an array only gives first element" (SC2128)

Tags: bash, flutter

### Problem

I'm trying to save a few CLI arguments into a variable, so it's convenient for me to use later.
This works but is quite verbose:

- `flutter run --dart-define=SENTRY_DSN_CLIENT_KEY=${APP1_SENTRY_DSN_CLIENT_KEY} --dart-define=MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN=${APP1_MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN}`

Unfortunately, neither of the following, concise options work. The 2nd `--dart-define` is not available in the app. I've tried:

- `flutter run $APP1_DART_DEFINE_FLAGS`
- `flutter run "${APP1_DART_DEFINE_FLAGS[@]}"`

**How do I workaround an issue which seems to be inside the `flutter run` tool?**

---

### Related problems

This seems to be highly related to (but I don't have control over fixing this):

- Documented as [SC2128: Expanding an array without an index only gives the first element.](https://www.shellcheck.net/wiki/SC2128)
- in [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47367985/expanding-a-bash-array-only-gives-the-first-element)

### My env file

```bash
export APP1_SENTRY_DSN_CLIENT_KEY=...
export APP1_MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN=...
export APP1_DART_DEFINE_FLAGS="--dart-define=SENTRY_DSN_CLIENT_KEY=${APP1_SENTRY_DSN_CLIENT_KEY} --dart-define=MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN=${APP1_MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN}"
```

Comment: in your `env` file you define `APP1_SENTRY_DS` but when defining `APP1_DART_DEFINE_FLAGS` you reference a different variable `APP1_SENTRY_DSN_CLIENT_KEY`; I can't tell if you have a typo in the `env` file, a typo in what you've posted in the question, or if there are more entries in your `env` file that are not shown here ... ??

Comment: nowhere in the question do you show the creation/population of an array so not sure where the reference to `SC21281` comes into play here; did you generate the `SC2128`  and if so could you provide the complete set of code you supplied to shellcheck.net?

Comment: **1.** Sorry @markp-fuso, that's a typo in the question. It doesn't look like that on my computer. I've fixed that. **2.** I did get that warning from shellcheck.net which is what prompted me to write that. I can't reproduce it now 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use bash arrays. Properly quote arguments.

```
APP1_DART_DEFINE_FLAGS=(
   "--dart-define=SENTRY_DSN_CLIENT_KEY=${APP1_SENTRY_DSN_CLIENT_KEY}"
   "--dart-define=MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN=${APP1_MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN}"
)
flutter run "${APP1_DART_DEFINE_FLAGS[@]}"
```

Comment: I've confirmed the variable can be expanded well (`echo "${APP1_DART_DEFINE_FLAGS[@]}"`), however the 2nd environment variable is still not available in the app.  I tried in both bash and zsh.

Comment: @BenButterworth add `set -xv` (enable debugging) just before `flutter` call, run script again, and review the debug output; does the array reference get expanded correctly? wondering if this is a `bash` issue or a `flutter` issue

Comment: Oh, I've just tried it again. And it works fine. Thanks a lot for your help and attention. So the problem was I wasn't creating an array. But why wasn't my definition of `APP1_DART_DEFINE_FLAGS` okay?

Comment: Also, is there a way to access `APP1_DART_DEFINE_FLAGS` in a `Makefile`. Look's like it doesn't show up .